# Efficiently color coding the text in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox in which a user can type some text with is color code on the fly by following rules.

1. `{ } ( ) | . (dot)` These characters should be red.
2. `[A-Z] [a-z] [0-9]` underscore and hyphen. These should be dark-grey.
3. everything else should be blue.

Right now I have this code on the event when the contents of the box change.
This method is invoked whenever there is a change detected in the contents of the text box.

```
public void colorCode() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rtb.Text.Length ; i++) {
         rtb.Select(i,1); //select a single character
         char ch = rtb.Text[i];
         if (ch == '{' || ch == '}' || 
             ch == '(' || ch == ')' ||
             ch == '.') 
             rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
         else if (isAlphaNumeric(ch)) 
             rtb.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGrey;
         else
             rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

As you can see this can be very slow when there are hundreds of characters. How can I improve this situation.

Comment: You may try to queue updates instead of running them after each change, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15587767/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr A more elaborate answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can use an editor, that supports syntax highlighting like [AvalonEdit](http://avalonedit.net). Within the [documentation](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/) you can find [how to define your own rules](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/html/4d4ceb51-154d-43f0-b876-ad9640c5d2d8.htm).

Comment: Not sure if it helps here but you can try us do a supend/resumeLayout around the loop.. - Or refresh only every second. -

Comment: Try to use [FastColoredTextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: @Oliver Thanks, it turned out to be exactly what I wanted. I will use it in my project but I will still try to write custom solution in hope of learning new things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do it on the KeyUp event so you're only looking at the single character that changed.  Not sure if this would be much faster if at all.

```
private void rtb_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod
         rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense but this should have been a comment not an answer.I am not going to but somebody may down-vote this answer. Now about your solution, How will I know exactly where the change happened. It may be in between the content that is already in the text-box.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question about where the change happened.  The KeyUp event will have an event arg that will tell you what key was pressed so you can evaluate at that point what color the single character should be instead of looping through all the previously entered text.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: Suppose this is the text inside the box `abcdef..((` now the user places the cursor next to the letter `c` then  presses `{`. Now by your logic I know what key was pressed but i don't at which position in the string.

Comment: The position doesn't matter, you only care about what character was entered.

Comment: the position matters because it is **required** to give the character a specific color. See my code `rtb.SelectionColor` and `rtb.select(position,length)`

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand here but aren't you using the position & length because you're looping through all of the characters.  Using the keyup event gives you the one character the user just pressed so you don't need to know where it's at in the string.  By using this event you know that 1) the character is the new character entered so you have it isolated.  2) what character it is so you can determine what color to make it.
I've updated the answer with a code sample, am I completely misunderstanding what you're attempting to do?